# Regular Expression for mobile numbers?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want regex for mobile number validation in java script that may be 10 digit to 20 digit and separated by comma

ex;
the user can enter 10 digit phone number alone (1234567890) or enter 10 to 20 digit phone number(1234567890123465),on both numbers separated by comma (1234567890,123456789043543,1234567890345,) but if once he going to enter a number ,it should be 10 digit to 20 digit and it may start with '+91' or '0' like this
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work.

```
/^(\+91\d{8,18}|0\d{0,19})(,\+91\d{8,18}|,0\d{0,19})*$/g
```

`\+91\d{8,18}` means starts with `+91` after that there can be more 8-18 digits. As there is 2 digits already in the beginning (`91`) total digits will be 10-20.

0\d{0,19} has also same meaning like above.

If you want to match strings like 123456789043543,1234567890345 etc which does not start with either `+91` or `0` Then simple `/^+\d{10-20}(,\d{10-20})*$/g` will do.

Comment: i tried this var num="+911678686786711,112345678";.. but it validate first number only.after the comma its not,the above value is wrong one but the exp which u given does not show error.it accepting that

Comment: You didn't specify it properly so I showed you 2 regexes. You also didn't tell whether number will be separated by `,` or it'll contain it. Post a number of valid input numbers. Then we can understand a little bit more. Also read the last paragraph of my answer. You specified `123456789043543,1234567890345` but didn't specified they are valid or invalid.

Comment: I tried like this../^(\+91\d{8,18}|0\d{9,18})((,\+91\d{8,18})|(,0\d{9,18}))*$/g...its suits for my code..Thanks a lot shiplu